# Retina Macbook is emitting a noise from under keyboard

Tags: mac

The noise is not coming from the speakers and appears to be coming from the left side of the keyboard. Nothing I do with the volume changes the noise. You can listen to it here: https://soundcloud.com/steve-melvin/retina-macbook-noise

Comment: What noise ? I would not call that noise.

Comment: I can hear a noise (listening through some decent headphones).  What I can hear is a high pitched buzzing noise, which plays for approx 1 sec, then off for a second, then on for a second again.  Does the sound change if you change the screen brightness?  Another idea: is the sound different when the machine is fully charged / discharged?

Comment: @Ashley: Yes that is the noise I am talking about. I've tried changing the screen brightness, keyboard brightness, charger plugged in/unplugged, and doing CPU/GPU intensive things. Nothing seems to change it.

Comment: Good experiments... sadly my guess is that the noise is originating from a failing component on the logic board :(  Is the machine under warranty?  Do you have a local Apple Store?

Comment: @Ashley: Seems like it's not a persistent noise. Right now I can't hear it, in fact, I've forgotten all about it until a couple days ago when it popped up again for a few minutes. It's a company laptop so I'm not super worried, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad it isn't a huge problem. My external monitor makes a high pitched buzzing noise (varies over time and with the monitor brightness) which drives me nuts sometimes. I've written up our discussion in a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

(Writing this up from a discussion in the comments, to help future readers...)

The noise in the sound recording is a high pitched buzzing noise, which plays for approx 1 sec, then off for a second, then on for a second again.

Some suggestions of things to try, in order to isolate the noise to a particular part of the system:

- change the screen brightness
- change the keyboard brightness
- test with the main battery discharged & charged
- test with a pair of headphones plugged in
- test with mains charger plugged in & removed
- test with an application generating high CPU load
- test with an application generating high GPU load